# Stability in the Finite Difference Method where we have source $f$

Tags: numerical-methods, stability-in-odes, finite-difference-methods

I was studying the finite difference scheme:
$$u^{n+1}_j=\frac{u^{n}_{j+1}+u^{n}_{j-1}}{2}-\frac{c\delta t}{2 \delta x}(u^{n}_{j+1}+u^{n}_{j-1})+\delta t f^n_j.$$ for $n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $j \in \mathbb{Z}$.
My question is that I tired to prove it's stability in $l^2$, by using Fourier transform, I had the following equality:

$$U^{n+1}_k=(cos(k.\delta x)-\frac{c.\delta t}{\delta x }.i.sin(k.\delta x))U^n_k+\delta tf^n_k$$
if $A=(cos(k.\delta x)-\frac{c.\delta t}{\delta x }.i.sin(k.\delta x))$
then we'll have:
$$U^{n+1}_k=A.U^{n}_k+\delta tf^n_k$$
But I can't figure out how to prove:(for some $C>0$) $$||U^{n+1}_k||<C||U^{n}_k||$$

Comment: Did you mean the second term on the right side to be a difference?

Comment: Stability is always about the homogeneous part of the equation, what kind/type of result do you expect when including the inhomogeneity?

Comment: So we don’t need to consider the $f$ term

Comment: Exactly. From your calculations you should see that you get stability in the mentioned sense for $c\cdot δt<δx$. For accurate results one usually finds that $δt$ needs to be much smaller.